# Woocommerce reduce stock quantity action hook

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook

i am using following code for Woocommerce Product publish, update hook and it's work perfect for me :

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'filter_post_data' , '99', 2 );
function filter_post_data( $data , $postarr ) {
    $sum = $_POST['wpcf']['ptchq'] + $_POST['wpcf']['monivong'];
    $_POST['_stock'] = $sum;
    return $data;
}
```

i am add two custom text field and add that field sum in product stock quantity in admin side.

Now my question is that how can i get after order complete reduce stock quantity action hook. so using that hook i can reduce stock in my custom field in admin side product.

Thanks,
Ketan.

Comment: It seems ot me that function does nothing,it returns the same data you passed to it

Answer (score 1):

The hook that runs when stock is changed is

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_product_set_stock', $this );
```

You can see it in the [Product Abstract](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php#L247)

Comment: Unfortunately the hook isn´t called when the quantity is reduced by ordering a product. Or updating a variety.